# Getting a position from list view and saving in pref file in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to make a simple Top Trumps app in Android. I have used SQL lite open helper to store the details of each top trump card.

At the moment I have a browse card class which shows the cards names using a list view. When someone clicks on the card name I want it to display the correct card and get the details of the card using my database.

I was thinking of doing this by getting the position of the list view so when the user clicks on the card it will get the position and display the correct details for the card chosen.

I was wondering if this was possible and was thinking I could save the position in a prefs file?

This is the code for my class.

```
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Browse extends Activity {

private ListView mainListView;  
private ArrayAdapter<Card> listAdapter;  

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout2);

    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView);  

    DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    // Remember to drop existing table if it exists
    dh.removeAll();

    // Insert 6 cards into the database
    Log.d("Database: ", "Inserting values..");
    dh.addCard(new Card(1, "Katniss Evergreen", "11", "33", "55", "44"));
    dh.addCard(new Card(2, "Peeta Melark", "49", "44", "11", "65"));
    dh.addCard(new Card(3, "Gale Hawthrone", "87", "32", "98", "50"));
    dh.addCard(new Card(4, "Haymitch", "30", "32", "45", "31"));
    dh.addCard(new Card(5, "Effie Trinket", "65", "54", "21", "34"));
    dh.addCard(new Card(6, "President Snow", "23", "45", "67", "21"));

    List<Card> list = dh.getAll();  

    // Create ArrayAdapter using the list of cards
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Card>(this, R.layout.simplerow, list);

    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );  



    }


}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListView.setOnItemClickListener(listener);` for getting the list index.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use for my spinner and getting the position.

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int position = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            final Cursor cur = (Cursor) ((AdapterView<?>) spinner1).getItemAtPosition(position);
            residentName.setText(c.getString(1));
            Resident_Id.setText(c.getString(2));
```